# filter table based on date range selected via datepicker using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement a table filter by date range using one input bound to a datepicker. I've gone through few similar questions but none of those have the answer which matched my example.

So far I tried the below code but I didn't understand how to bind the datepicker and table together to proceed further. Any help is appreciated.

```js
$(document).on("click", "#datepicker .created_on", function() {
  var dataVal = $(this).text();
  if (dataVal != '') {
    $("#adv_filter tr:not('#table-header')").hide()
    $("#adv_filter tr[data-type='" + dataVal + "']").show();
  } else {
    $("#adv_filter tr").show()
  }
  isSelectFilter = true
});

(function($) {
  $('.datepicker').each(function() {
    $(this).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',          
    });
  });
}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<div class=" datepicker1" id="datepicker">
  <label for="datepicker">Date</label>
  <input type="text" style="width:120px;" class="created_on   required datepicker " data-placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" required="">
</div>
<table class="" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" id="adv_filter">
  <thead>
    <tr id="table-header">
      <th><label> NAME</label></th>
      <th><label> TYPE</label></th>
      <th><label>Doc</label></th>
      <th style="margin-left:10px"><label>Date</label></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="">
    <tr class="">
      <td><label>exmp1</label></td>
      <td><label>text</label></td>
      <td><label>word</label></td>
      <td><label style="margin-left:10px">18/6/17</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td><label>exmp1</label></td>
      <td><label>text</label></td>
      <td><label>word</label></td>
      <td><label style="margin-left:10px">20/10/12</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td><label>exmp1</label></td>
      <td><label>text</label></td>
      <td><label>word</label></td>
      <td><label style="margin-left:10px">5/10/19</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td><label>exmp1</label></td>
      <td><label>text</label></td>
      <td><label>word</label></td>
      <td><label style="margin-left:10px">5/10/19</label></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The datepicker works for you locally but not in the fiddle because you didn't include a reference to jQueryUI. I've done that for you and moved the logic in to a snippet in the question. However you've not included the `triggerFocus()` function

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan   thx for the ref. I removed the triggerFocus.

Comment: if you want to do this using html table and plain JS, you first need to create a dataset, e.g. array of objects, based on date, then use that array to create table rows' html. finally append that html to the table. otherwise you can use plugins such as jqx grid or others which provide built in filter functionality

Comment: @MuhammadMuradHaider is there any other way, other than creating a table dynamically because there are other functionalities involved in the table which increases complexity if I go for a dynamic table. I cannot use the library due to some restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution which transforms the date in the same format in the rows:
I have changed the event click to change

```js
$(document).on("change", "#datepicker .created_on", function() {
  var dataVal = $(this).datepicker('getDate');//get date from datepicker
  dataVal= $.datepicker.formatDate("d/m/y", dataVal);//set format date like in the rows
  //console.log(dataVal, typeof dataVal);
  if (dataVal != '') {
    $("tr:not('#table-header')").hide();//hide all rows
    //show rows with the same date selected
    $("label:contains('" +  dataVal + "')").each(function(){
      $(this).closest('tr').show();
    });
  }  
});

(function($) {
  $('.datepicker').each(function() {
    $(this).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
      onClose: function() {
        //triggerFocus();
      }
    });
  });
}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<div class="datepicker1" id="datepicker">
  <label for="datepicker">Date</label>
  <input type="text" style="width:120px;" class="created_on required datepicker" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" required="">
</div>
<table class="" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" id="">
  <thead>
    <tr id="table-header">
      <th><label> NAME</label></th>
      <th><label> TYPE</label></th>
      <th><label>Doc</label></th>
      <th style="margin-left:10px"><label>Date</label></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="">
    <tr class="">
      <td><label>exmp1</label></td>
      <td><label>text</label></td>
      <td><label>word</label></td>
      <td><label style="margin-left:10px">18/6/17</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td><label>exmp1</label></td>
      <td><label>text</label></td>
      <td><label>word</label></td>
      <td><label style="margin-left:10px">20/10/12</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td><label>exmp1</label></td>
      <td><label>text</label></td>
      <td><label>word</label></td>
      <td><label style="margin-left:10px">5/10/19</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td><label>exmp1</label></td>
      <td><label>text</label></td>
      <td><label>word</label></td>
      <td><label style="margin-left:10px">5/10/19</label></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler approach would be to look for the date in table cells (loop through table rows and check date value) and showing/hiding table row. you can add/remove css classes to/from particular rows based on your date criteria. css classes will handle showing/hiding thing. The snippet below should give you the idea. (try with date `5/10/19`, as other dates are having date format issues that you need to handle).

```js
$('#btnFilter').click(function() {
$('#tablebody tr').each(function() {
debugger;
var dt = new Date($(this).find('td:eq(3)').text());
var filterDate = new Date($('#date').val());
if(dt)
{
if(dt.getTime() == filterDate.getTime()) {
$(this).removeClass("hidden");
$(this).addClass("visible");
}
else {
$(this).removeClass("visible");
$(this).addClass("hidden");
}
}

});

});
```

```css
.visible {
display:block !important
}
.hidden {
display:none !important
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>date: </span><input type="text" id="date" />
<input type="button" id="btnFilter" value="Filter" />
<table id="table">
<thead>
    <tr id="table-header">
      <th><label> NAME</label></th>
      <th><label> TYPE</label></th>
      <th><label>Doc</label></th>
      <th style="margin-left:10px"><label>Date</label></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tablebody">
    <tr class="">
      <td><label>exmp1</label></td>
      <td><label>text</label></td>
      <td><label>word</label></td>
      <td><label style="margin-left:10px">18/6/17</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td><label>exmp1</label></td>
      <td><label>text</label></td>
      <td><label>word</label></td>
      <td><label style="margin-left:10px">20/10/12</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td><label>exmp1</label></td>
      <td><label>text</label></td>
      <td><label>word</label></td>
      <td><label style="margin-left:10px">5/10/19</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td><label>exmp1</label></td>
      <td><label>text</label></td>
      <td><label>word</label></td>
      <td><label style="margin-left:10px">5/10/19</label></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Murad, thanks for your quick response. is it not possible to do without Button and instead of typing the date manually, the user should select it from datepicker

Comment: button was just to give you an idea about filtering thing, you can capture `blur` event for your textbox instead of a button click.